# How to retrieve Windows Defender exclusions by PowerShell without truncation output

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

I want to write a PowerShell Script that displays all exclusions set in Windows Defender in Windows 10. So I already found out that this can be done by calling

```
Get-MpPreference | Select-Object -Property ExclusionPath
```

Which truncates the output if there are a lot of files and folders defined.

So I tried to add

```
Get-MpPreference | Select-Object -Property ExclusionPath | Out-String -width 1024
```

Which leads to a similar output: the string gets longer, but the truncation persists, only some whitespace is added to the end:

```
ExclusionPath                                                                                                                                                   
-------------                                                                                                                                                   
{C:\Users\Elvi\Documents\Assassin's Creed IV Black Flag, C:\Users\Elvi\Documents\Benutzerdefinierte Office-Vorlagen, C:\Users\Elvi\Documents\FHOA, C:\Users\Elvi\Documents\Gebuhrenzentrale...}



PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

So how can I prevent Powershell from truncating the output of the folders?

Comment: Expand the property - `Get-MpPreference | Select-Object -expand ExclusionPath`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get-MpPreference | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ExclusionPath

`-ExpandProperty` unravels the collection of ExclusionPath into separate lines, with each exclusion path on a new line.

`Out-String -Width`  or `Format-Table -Width` doesn't help enough in case the number of items is too high, Powershell just doesn't display more than the value of `$FormatEnumerationLimit` items.
So you could also set that to a higher value

```
$FormatEnumerationLimit=12
```

But then, what happens if there are more than 12 items (you could raise the number to 1500... output is still ugly)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, listing all entries expanded:

```
 Get-MpPreference | Select-Object -Property ExclusionPath -ExpandProperty ExclusionPath
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the output with the [Format-Table](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Format-Table?view=powershell-7&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-4.0) commandlet, e.g.

`Get-MpPreference | Select-Object -Property ExclusionPath | Format-Table -AutoSize`

Comment: Or simply dot reference it.  [(Get-MpPreference).ExclusionPath]  If all you want is one property. Otherwise, the Select-Object approach as noted is more prudent.

Comment: @spikey_richie: This solution does not work. In my case it gives
`ExclusionPath                                                                                                                                                                   
-------------                                                                                                                                                                   
{%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\NTuser.pol, %SystemRoot%\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\registry.pol, %SystemRoot%\System32\GroupPolicy\User\registry.pol, %windir%\Security\Database\*.chk...}`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$exclusions = Get-MpPreference
$exclusions.ExclusionPath
```

Comment: Please explain what this does and quote a reference